# Is there a way to seperate operators from number in a textfield when using getText()?

Tags: java, user-interface, calculator, gettext

This is the whole code.

```
package helwrld;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class SwingTrial {
    JButton b;
    private double num1;
    private double num2;
    private double result;
    private String opr = "";
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingTrial gui= new SwingTrial();
        gui.go();
    }
    public void go() {
    JFrame box1= new JFrame();
    final JTextField tf=new JTextField(); 
    tf.setBounds(100,50, 150,20); 
    final JButton b= new JButton("1");
    b.setBounds(30,30,60,60);
    final JButton c= new JButton("2");
    c.setBounds(30,100,60,60);
    final JButton d= new JButton("+");
    d.setBounds(30,170,60,60);
    final JButton e= new JButton("=");
    e.setBounds(30,240,60,60);
    final JButton g= new JButton("3");
    g.setBounds(30,310,60,60);
    
    
    
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {// listens for the "1" button being pressed, displays and stores the value in num1
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            
            String eNum= tf.getText()+b.getText();
            tf.setText(eNum);
        }
    });
    
    c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {// listens for the "2" button being pressed, displays and stores the value in num2
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            
            String eNum= tf.getText()+c.getText();
            tf.setText(eNum);
        }
    });
    
    g.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {// listens for the "2" button being pressed, displays and stores the value in num2
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            
            String eNum= tf.getText()+g.getText();
            tf.setText(eNum);
        }
    });
    d.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {// listens for the "+" button being pressed and displays it
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            opr="+";
            num1= Double.valueOf(tf.getText());
            String eNum= tf.getText()+d.getText();
            tf.setText(eNum);
            
        }
    });
    
    
    e.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Adds the sums of the two nums and displays them next to the original numbers.
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String value= tf.getText();
            char aChar=value.charAt(2);
            num2= Double.valueOf(aChar);
            opr="=";
            if(opr.equals("=")) {
                result= num1+num2;
                
            }
            else if(opr.equals("+")) {
                tf.setText("Can't do that");
            }
            String addAnswer= String.format("%.1f", result); 
            String eNum= tf.getText()+e.getText()+addAnswer;
            
            tf.setText(eNum);
            
        }
    });
    
    
    
    box1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    box1.add(b);
    box1.add(c);
    box1.add(d);
    box1.add(e);
    box1.add(g);
    box1.add(tf);
    box1.setLayout(null);

    box1.setSize(500,500);
    box1.setVisible(true);

    }   
}
```

At first it was just,

```
String value= tf.getText();
            char aChar=value.charAt(2);
            num2= Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
            opr="=";
            if(opr.equals("=")) {
                result= num1+num2;
                
            }
            else if(opr.equals("+")) {
                tf.setText("Can't do that");
            }
            String addAnswer= String.format("%.1f", result); 
            String eNum= tf.getText()+e.getText()+addAnswer;
            
            tf.setText(eNum);
```

But this gave me so many errors.
So I tried converting the string value from `getText()` to a char and then a double, but its giving a wrong answer.

```
String value= tf.getText();
            char aChar=value.charAt(2);
            num2= Double.valueOf(aChar);
            opr="=";
            if(opr.equals("=")) {
                result= num1+num2;
                
            }
            else if(opr.equals("+")) {
                tf.setText("Can't do that");
            }
            String addAnswer= String.format("%.1f", result); 
            String eNum= tf.getText()+e.getText()+addAnswer;
            
            tf.setText(eNum);
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get the value of the number at index 2 of `getText()`?

Comment: I'm trying to get it to ignore the operator sign so I can make the second number pressed equal to `num2`

Comment: You can use [String.substring()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-substring) if you know exactly where in `tf.getText()` the operators will be.

Comment: I know the last character is a number, so I am thinking of going along those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you will have to consider even multiple digits numbers (N > 9), float numbers and negative numbers (N < 0).

I would use a regular expression to find in your string what can be considered a number.

Here is an example but mind that:

1. numbers will need to be separated by a whitespace
2. you will have to iterate till the last match to find your number

```java
public static List<Double> getNumbersFromString(String input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([+-]?\\d+\\.?\\d+)|([+-]?\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        doubleList.add(Double.parseDouble(m.group()));
    }
    return doubleList;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = "1 + 2 - 30 * 5 / ( 3 + 4.3) + -120"; // tf.getText();

    // My suggestion
    List<Double> numbersFromString = getNumbersFromString(value);
    System.out.println(numbersFromString.get(numbersFromString.size() - 1));

    // Your code
    value = String.valueOf(value.charAt(value.length() - 1)); // gets the last char in _value_
    Double num2 = Double.parseDouble(value);
    System.out.println(num2);
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly new at programming and not too sure what this will do. Do you mind explaining it a little more?

Comment: I have detailed the code. I suggest you to try this code with a debugger to understand step by step what happen. Regular expression are a powerful way to parse a string and "Matcher" is the java object that will apply the expression on an input string like those that comes from tf.getText(). Please try the code above and accept my answer if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a fix for it:

```
   String value= tf.getText();
   value=String.valueOf(value.charAt(value.length()-1));// gets the last char in _value_
   num2= Double.parseDouble(value);
```

It looks kind of redundant for me, to save the `getText()` output to a string but it was the most comfortable way to get what I wanted.